# complex QUERY into VIEW with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a plan table looking like this :

[image]

I wanted an SQL that would give me a select for each artikelnr, date, and jahr_kw (calendar week) where if an entry is null, it would take the previous date's entry. This was given to be this:

```
select distinct artikelnr
            , datum
            , jahr_kw
            , first_value(menge) over (partition by artikelnr, jahr_kw 
                              order by (case when menge is not null then 1 else 2 end), datum desc
                             ) as imputed_Jahr_KW

from test_table
where datum between '2021-02-01' and '2021-03-01' -- for example
```

Notice the where clause.

Now my question, how do I make a VIEW of this query, where I can select the dates (datum) in a where clause?

Comment: You don't select dates in a view.  Perhaps you want a user-defined function that returns a table?

Comment: make a view without where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a Table-Valued Function would be best

**Example**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_SomeName](@Date1 date,@Date2 date)
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    
select distinct artikelnr
            , datum
            , jahr_kw
            , first_value(menge) over (partition by artikelnr, jahr_kw 
                              order by (case when menge is not null then 1 else 2 end), datum desc
                             ) as imputed_Jahr_KW

from test_table
where datum between @Date1 and @Date2


);
```

**Usage**

```
Select * From [dbo].[tvf_SomeName]('2021-02-01','2021-03-01')
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot!..Errr... Is it possible to get it distinct? That would be fabulous:)

Comment: @KingsleyObeng Always happy to help.   Not sure what you mean by DISTINCT, you already have DISTINCT in the TVF.  In the usage... you can Select DISTINCT ColX,ColY From [dbo].[tvf_SomeName]('2021-02-01','2021-03-01')

Comment: @KingsleyObeng A Table-Valued Function is much like a stored procedure (sans updates) with some added benefits.  The results can be consumed in a query i.e. a JOIN or CROSS APPLY.   Personally I avoid views because they can get expensive... especially with large tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a indexed view for your purpose.

The index which need the form seen below, will make the query quick

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Yourdb.test_table(artikelnr int,datum Date,jahr_kw smallint,menge INT )
> GO
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE VIEW Yourdb.testview
>     WITH SCHEMABINDING
>        AS  
>           select distinct artikelnr
>             , datum
>             , jahr_kw
>             , first_value(menge) over (partition by artikelnr, jahr_kw 
>                               order by (case when menge is not null then 1 else 2 end),   datum desc
>                              ) as imputed_Jahr_KW
>
>          from test.test_table
>     GO
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

> ```
>     --Create an index on the view.
>     CREATE  INDEX IDX_V1   ON Yourdb.testview (datum);
>     GO
> GO
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c78ed8965d7621d64eec9d7017672ae5)*

Usage

```
SELECT * FROM Yourdb.testview WHERE where datum between '2021-02-01' and '2021-03-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `distinct` and simply create the view

```
create view SomeView
as
select        artikelnr
            , datum
            , jahr_kw
            , first_value(menge) over (partition by artikelnr, jahr_kw 
                              order by (case when menge is not null then 1 else 2 end), datum desc
                             ) as imputed_Jahr_KW

from test_table
```

Then since `datum` is projected by the view without any query operators being applied, you can filter against it efficiently from outside the view.

```
select *
from SomeView
where datum between '2021-02-01' and '2021-03-01'
```

EG:

```
drop table if exists test_table

create table test_table
(
  artikelnr int,
  datum varchar(20),
  jahr_kw int, 
  menge int
)
insert into test_table
values 
 (1,'01.Jan',1,10),
 (1,'01.Jan',2,7),
 (1,'01.Jan',3,1),
 (1,'02.Jan',1,null),
 (1,'02.Jan',2,5),
 (1,'02.Jan',3,2),
 (1,'03.Jan',1,null),
 (1,'03.Jan',2,4),
 (1,'03.Jan',3,3),
 (1,'04.Jan',1,null),
 (1,'04.Jan',2,9),
 (1,'04.Jan',3,4),
 (1,'01.Jan',1,20),
 (1,'01.Jan',2,10),
 (1,'01.Jan',3,4),
 (1,'02.Jan',1,30),
 (1,'02.Jan',2,20),
 (1,'02.Jan',3,3),
 (1,'03.Jan',1,null),
 (1,'03.Jan',2,15),
 (1,'03.Jan',3,2)
 

 
 go

create or alter view vT
as
 select artikelnr
            , datum
            , jahr_kw
            , first_value(menge) over (partition by artikelnr, jahr_kw 
                              order by (case when menge is not null then 1 else 2 end), datum desc
                             ) as imputed_Jahr_KW

from test_table

go

 select distinct artikelnr
            , datum
            , jahr_kw
            , first_value(menge) over (partition by artikelnr, jahr_kw 
                              order by (case when menge is not null then 1 else 2 end), datum desc
                             ) as imputed_Jahr_KW

from test_table
where datum between '01.Jan' and '03.Jan' -- for example


select *
from vt 
where datum between '01.Jan' and '03.Jan' -- for example
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly, because it uses the whole table first, before applying the where clause. This can be seen when omitting the date 1.1. from the where clause , and finding results from kw1 (1.1)  ie 10, in your result.

Comment: No, that's just because the `first_value` requires some scanning.  It has nothing to do with whether there's a view.  See updated answer with example.